# How to hide portion of an element in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the sidebar example from W3 school, please check it out:

[Slid_show_link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push)

The problem is, I want to tweak it a little bit, so that when this page is opened on a iphone 6, the side navi bar will only show icons, please see my code:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}
.col-sm-2 {
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!-- Font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jquery ui -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="row">
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#main"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="hidden-sm">About</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="hidden-sm">Service</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="hidden-sm">Client</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="hidden-sm">Contact</span></a>
  </div>

  <div id="main" class="col-sm-10" style="background-color:pink;">
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="by_state_table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th><th>col6</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to bootstrap 3, and I manage to hide those phrase in the sidebar on a iphone 6 and manage to create a grid system on this page.
What I want to achieve is:

(1) show only the icons on **iphone6** and make the sidebar shrink to the icon's size.

(2)only show 3 cols of the table on an **iphone6**.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you guys in advance!

EDIT________________________________________________

I have tried to edit my code as @jogoe suggested, please see my code in action:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5ieutCzHQT87if65ZY5f?p=preview

The one of the OPEN should be hidden on small screen, it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

> (1) show only the icons on iphone6 and make the sidebar shrink to the icon's size.

You can give your desktop-sidebar the class: `hidden-xs` and create your new sidebar and give it the class e.g.: `visible-xs-1`

This will result in your desktop-sidebar being hidden, and the mobile-sidebar (where you just put your icons in and style it how you want it to look in mobile) being shown.

You can read up on that [here.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

> (2)only show 3 cols of the table on an iphone6.

You should be able to do this by adding bootstrap classes again. E.g.:

```
<th class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">col1</th>
```

Check this out [here.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Comment: I create a new side bar and give it a class visible-xs, it's not showing when the old one is hidden...